# How to convert sql recursion to javascript

Tags: node.js, postgresql, directed-graph

When I try to search possible paths from a vertex in a directed graph. I have a SQL recursion to do that. However, I don't want to use a database so would like to convert SQL recursion to node js recursive function without SQL query but I can't figure it out.
How can I do it? Here is my SQL recursion

```
drop table edges;
create table edges (route_id integer, stuff_id integer, option_id integer);
    insert into edges (route_id, stuff_id, option_id) values (36, 73, 75);
    insert into edges (route_id, stuff_id, option_id) values (37, 73, 74);
    insert into edges (route_id, stuff_id, option_id) values (38, 73, 88);
    insert into edges (route_id, stuff_id, option_id) values (39, 82, 73);
 WITH RECURSIVE search_path (depth, option_tree) AS (
  SELECT 1, ARRAY[e.stuff_id]
  FROM edges e
  UNION ALL
  SELECT f.depth + 1, option_tree || d.option_id
  FROM edges d, search_path f
  WHERE f.option_tree[array_length(option_tree, 1)] = d.stuff_id
  )
  SELECT * FROM search_path
  WHERE option_tree[1] = 82
  ORDER BY depth DESC;
```

We can test SQL via https://extendsclass.com/postgresql-online.html

Comment: "*I don't want to use a database*" - then where do you get your data from, and in what format? And then the question has absolutely nothing to do with postgres any more.

Comment: edges will be like this:
`const edges = [{
    stuff_id: 73,
    option_id: 75,
    route_id: 36
  },
  {
    stuff_id: 73,
    option_id: 74,
    route_id: 37
  },
  {
    stuff_id: 73,
    option_id: 88,
    route_id: 39
  },
  {
    stuff_id: 82,
    option_id: 73,
    route_id: 38
  }]`

and I won't do anything with Postgres.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include the data with proper formatting

Comment: Don't let yourself be influenced by the declarative SQL algorithm with its set-based `UNION` semantics. It seems you're looking for a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm)